# OpenOffice, listen socket (Windows XP)

Tags: sockets, openoffice.org

How can I make OpenOffice 3.2.1 to listen a socket (Windows XP)?
I used
`soffice "-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=12345;urp;"`
or
 `soffice "-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=12345;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager"`

Have tryed different ports..
OOo starts, but netstat doesn't show any connection with such port number.
I thought it's because of some turned off win services on my machine
, so I tryed the same thing on another computer - no results

Searching google etc. it seems that I'm the only one with such a problem %) It looks strange..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give [`netstat`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netstat.mspx?mfr=true) `-a` flag to see listening ports.